# Полупрозрачное окно на java которое игнорирует клики мышкой

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Встала задача создать приложение одним из компонентов которого будет полупрозрачное окно которое находится всегда на переднем плане, при этом ведет себя так как будто его нет. То-есть если за этим коном находится приложение то на нажатия мышки будет реагировать только это приложение. Реально ли сделать такое с помощью java? Вопрос только в игнорировании кликов.

Comment: у JFrame уже есть прозрачный слой - Glass Pane. зачем вам нужно это?

Comment: Здравствуйте спасибо за ответ, я возможно упустил что то в вопросе (впервые тут) хотел сделать что то вроде гаджетов как в win7 но так что-бы отображались поверх всех окон и на них нельзя было кликнуть (что то вроде фантомного окна)

Comment: для подобной задачи лучше взять C++/C#

Comment: Собственно зачем этот слой так и не понятно, какие функции он должен выполнять?

Comment: Просто существовать )